# iOS In-app purchases

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I know that there are many related questions and I've read them all but still didn't find answer, so please read my question.

Problem:
I Try to get product id with SKProductRequest, but only invalid id returns. 
Try to make purchase - unable to connect to iTunes error.

- In App Purchase enabled at Provisioning Portal
- IAP products are added to the application in iTunes Connect with Cleared for Sale checked (status is Ready to Submit)
- Bundle ID from iTunes Connect and *.plist are the same
- Target iOs is 3.0 and above
- Use full product id (*.*.*.ProductID) when doing SKProductRequest.
- Tried reinstall app, iTunes etc.
- Log out from Store in Settings

Also, I use Phonegap and InAppPurchaseManager plugin but I believe problem is somewhere in store settings and not in Phonegap.

Any thoughts what I have missed?

The final thing I was thought about is approving 'iOS Paid Applications' contract. They finally approved it but IAP still doesn't work.

Please help! Can't be there are no solutions.

Comment: +1 this is a horrible topic as you don't get any info on why the id's are invalid. I might have the same problem as you have atm. I hope someone comes up with an answer :)

Comment: Is this an update to an existing app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer! In ALL guides I have only seen the wording 'Use full product id (AppID.ProductID) when doing request', but actually you should specify ProductID in this form at the iTunes Connect! So, my ProductID is 'com.test1.testProduct1' and I send exactly the same ID in all requests. The problem is solved!