# Using sandbox user to test In App Purchase

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

When I test my Cordova app (with [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase)) all in app product IDs are reported invalid.

I tried to restore purchase (which calls `store.refresh()`) and a login prompt appeared. I log in with sandbox account but it asks for my billing information which it shouldn't. How do I test this app correctly?

Things I have tried:

- Sign out from iOS App Store
- Close iTunes on my Mac
- Uninstall app, restart the phone, reinstall app
- Install app via Xcode
- Create a fresh sandbox user in US region
- I never use sandbox account to sign in in the App Store application or in the iOS settings. I also never verified its email.

About my app's environment:

- I have completed paid apps contract
- The app is waiting for review submission
- The binary is signed with developer key
- One in app product is waiting for review submission, others are waiting for screenshot
- All in app products are consumable
- I have tested the code on Android and it is working correctly. I used  same product ID in iTunes connect as in Play Store.
- I noticed that app produces sandbox push notification token
- The devices tested are an iPhone 4 running iOS 6 and a jailbroken iPad 2 running iOS 6

Comment: Have you solved the issue? This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449571/289912

Comment: The app is festival-specific. I contacted Apple DTS but they haven't solve it in time for launch so I didn't followed up. One of the thing they checked is that I have used the correct product ID.

Comment: What was the correct product id like? `"com.test.app.product01"` ?

Comment: I used `product01` and it works fine (from their side).